# Measuring micro-amps with INA series

Tags: microcontroller, current-measurement, low-power, shunt

I'm designing BLE devices and other low power embedded systems that can consume very low energy in the range of a few micro-amps.

I can't afford any expensive precision multimeters. Hence, I'm trying to design a simple system to measure micro-amps with the INA series chips and a micro-controller. I currently don't have access to designing custom PCBs with SMD chips and precise components. Therefore, I'm sticking with the INA series modules which can be found easily on aliexpress.

I found 3 modules the [INA219](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina219.pdf), [INA226](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina226.pdf) and [INA3221](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina3221.pdf).
They are very similar using an I2C bus to communicate but have different resolutions. Based on the datasheet, taking INA219 for example has a max shunt voltage of 40mV and a 12-bit ADC which gives a LSB step size of 10uV. By using a 10ohm resistor as a shunt, I get a resolution of 1uA.

In theory, this should be perfect to calculate microcurrents. However, I read in multiple forums that INA219 series are great for measuring milli-amps but not micro-amps and recommended using a traditional op-amp amplifier circuit. I'm currently not able to do so, so I'm trying to see why do these modules cause problem in measuring low currents and what I can do to improve it?

[EDIT]
Answering some of the questions from the comments.
Firstly, I perfectly understand that SMD components are unavoidable in professional design. However, at the current situation I need a quick low cost and relatively reliable solution to measure uA to a single digit. Hence, the question and I'm also curious why it would be a problem if it is?

As this will act as an ammeter, I can attach the shunt resistor in either high-side or low-side of the circuit. The system is operating in a standard room temperature of about 27 degrees Celsius. The precision needed is to have a step size of 1uA.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when you're using BLE-enabled devices, you won't get around SMD technology, and measuring microamperes with free-flying wires is a no-starter, to be honest, since you'll then have to deal with noise picked up by the wires. So, no matter what amplifier you end up building/using, sit down, grab your favourite EDA software and design a PCB, and get it produced for single-digit euros (e.g. at jlcpcb). Doesn't have to be overly complex. You're looking, in fact, for "ultra-low offset + low drift" amplifiers; the MAX4238 or 4239 might be your choice.

Comment: also, you might be interested in the [µCurrent Gold](http://alternatezone.com/electronics/ucurrent/uCurrentArticle.pdf), which at least gets a lot of publicity, and the design files are freely available.

Comment: If you are *designing BLE devices* AND you *currently don't have access to designing custom PCBs with SMD chips*, then I suspect you are out of your depth and need to rethink things.

Comment: I have already design and developed the BLE boards. At the current moment I can't afford the time and resources to design another pcb board for this. Hence, my question is if it's possible to use the INA modules to complete the task. And more importantly if it's not, what's the reason?

Comment: You should add a circuit that shows where you will be placing current shunt resistors in order to test your modules. Also specify what supply rails are available for this task and precisely define how much accuracy you require (and what temperature you will measure at) in those measurements.

Comment: For a one shot evaluation you can probably just put a resistor in the ground lead with a cap across it and watch it with a scope so that you see all of idle, transmit, and receive.  Where a chip like the INA219 really shines is if you want a running log of operations - it's especially nice as a cheap solution you could put on a prototype and leave running to log usage in simulated typical operation, vs. a one-time bench test.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want microamp **resolution** but you do not need microamp **accuracy**. Is that right?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson yes but within acceptable uncertainty